# Distributed file processing in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, batch-processing, apache-flink

I have a large number of compressed tar files, where each tar itself contains several files. I want to extract these files and I want to use hadoop or a similar technique to speedup the the processing. Are there any tools for this kind of problem? As far as I know hadoop and similar frameworks like spark or flink do not use files directly and don't give you access to the filesystem directly. I also want to do some basic renaming of the extracted files and move them into appropriate directories.

I can image a solution where one creates a list of all tar files. This list is then passed to the mappers and a single mapper extracts one file from the list. Is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: You probably have to write a custom input format for Hadoop, Flink or Spark to implement this.
In the InputFormat code, you can treat the files in every way you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to instruct MapReduce to use an input format where the input to each Mapper is a single file. (from https://code.google.com/p/hadoop-course/source/browse/HadoopSamples/src/main/java/mr/wholeFile/WholeFileInputFormat.java?r=3)

```Java
public class WholeFileInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<NullWritable, BytesWritable> {

  @Override
  protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path filename) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public RecordReader<NullWritable, BytesWritable> createRecordReader(
    InputSplit inputSplit, TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException,
  InterruptedException {
    WholeFileRecordReader reader = new WholeFileRecordReader();
    reader.initialize(inputSplit, context);
    return reader;
  }
}
```

Then, in your mapper, you can use the Apache commons compress library to unpack the tar file https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/examples.html

you don't need to pass a list of files to Hadoop, just put all the files in a single HDFS directory, and use that directory as your input path.

Comment: This sounds like a good solution. I will try to implement it.

Comment: if tars are few and very large, the small number of mappers will be a performance bottleneck

Comment: The question states "I have a large number of compressed tar files"

Comment: that's what i wonder about, what is "large" in OPs understanding

Comment: probably the better idea would be using one job to decompress jars and second job to process unpacked files

Comment: The question doesn't say what is to be done with the unpacked files, whether they just get written back to HDFS or processed in some way.

Comment: ok, anyhow the justification for using a cluster for unpacking jars would be a really enormous number of them. let's wait what OP says

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I was on vacation. Actually my dataset are approx. 1000 tar files, each around 500mb. In each tar there are another 10000 files, some of them are .tar.gz files, others are pdf. But they don't have the correct file ending. I want to extract all these files. The first step is simply to untar the tar files. The second step is then to process (check the type, uncompress, rename) the files within in the tar file.

Comment: @mattinbits If I read your solution correctly, you suggest to open the tar files and process the content of the tar as a byte array file within the mapper. I was wondering if I could do all files processing within the mapper. What happens for example if the file content is larger then the main memory, say 8 gb? I think distcp should do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Distcp moves files from one place to another, you can take a look at its docs but I don't think it offers any decompress or unpack capability? If a file is bigger than main memory, you probably will get some out of memory errors. 8gb is not very big for a Hadoop cluster, how many machines do you have?

Comment: I don't think that I can use distcp, but its functioning should be similar to my needs. I am studying its source code (I don't fully understand it yet) and it seems that the mapper receives the input file name and the status of the input files as key/values and performs the copying. But maybe you are right and I should just process the whole open file.

Comment: Ok, I think distcp creates a list of files and directories to be copied.